# Why aren't some of my Junit classes being run?

Tags: junit

I have a problem using Junit tests with Java and Eclipse. All of my tests run just fine when I invoke them standalone. By this I mean that HDLmTreeTest, HDLmTreeTest1, and HDLmTreeTest2 all run fine when I run them by themselves. However, I have a Java source module with all of the test files in it. See below.

```
package com.headlamp;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses({HDLmConfigTest.class, HDLmDefinesTest.class,     
                HDLmErrorTest.class, HDLmStringTest.class, HDLmTreeTest.class,
                HDLmTreeTest1.class, HDLmTreeTest2.class,
                  HDLmModTest.class, HDLmBuildJSTest.class, HDLmFindTest.class,
                  HDLmAssertTest.class, HDLmBuildLinesTest.class, HDLmUtilityTest.class,
                  HDLmSavedChangeTest.class, HDLmCurlApacheTest.class, HDLmMainTest.class,
                  HDLmJettyTest.class, HDLmCurlJettyTest.class, HDLmEditorServletTest.class,
                  HDLmApacheTest.class, HDLmProxyTest.class, HDLmSessionTest.class,
                  HDLmLogMsgTest.class, HDLmMatchTest.class, HDLmImageInformationTest.class,
                  HDLmClusteringTest.class, HDLmJsonTest.class})
class HDLmAllTests { }
```

When I run this file, all of my tests get invoked except for HDLmTreeTest1.class and HDLmTreeTest2.class. I should say that HDLmTreeTest1.class and HDLmTreeTest2.class were just recently created and added to the SelectClasses list. For some reason, they are not invoked, but all of the other classes are invoked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out (with lots of online help). The problem was the name(s) of my test classes. Test classes (the names of test classes) must end with 'Test' or 'Tests'. They can not end with 'Test1' or 'Test2'. That was my error. I changed the class names and the problem went away. See https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit5-test-suites-examples/ for some details.